# THREE.js MeshPhongMaterial self illumination

Tags: three.js

I want to set self illumination for a MeshPhongMaterial from it's map.
I tried copying the `material.map` to `material.emissiveMap` and set emissive to white, but all I get it's full white:

```
mat.emissiveMap = mat.map;
mat.emissive.setHex(0xffffff);
mat.emissiveIntensity = 1;
```

[image]

Where I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok... I forgot to set `.needsUpdate`...

```
mat.emissiveMap = mat.map;
mat.emissive.setHex(0xFFFFFF);
mat.needsUpdate = true;
```